# Virtual function pointer to a function in a derived class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, function-pointers, virtual-functions

I'm trying to see if the following is possible. I'm still on an old Visual Studio 2008 C++ compiler, so bear with me.

Say, I have two classes derived from a single class. Both have the same function that I want to pass as a pointer to be called from a static function.

Here's pseudocode:

```
class CDlg1 : public CDialog
{
    virtual void func1(int v)
    {
        wprintf(L"CDlg1::func1 was called, v=%d\n", v);
    }

    void do_delayed_call()
    {
        delayed_call_func1(func1);
    }
}

class CDlg2 : public CDialog
{
    virtual void func1(int v)
    {
        wprintf(L"CDlg2::func1 was called, v=%d\n", v);
    }

    void do_delayed_call()
    {
        delayed_call_func1(func1);
    }
}



static void delayed_call_func1(void* pfn)
{
    //... some additional action
    //int v = something

    //Call pfn() after a delay
    pfn(v);
}
```

I can't figure out, do I need to template for this function pointer?

Comment: Neither `func1` is compatible with `void*`, nor can they be called with only an `int` argument.  They are both member functions.  You'll need a free function or a `static` member function to wrap the call, along with an object of the appropriate type.

Comment: Please provide the relevant details of the implementation of `CDialog` (or if it's irrelevant, remove the base). As it stands, this is not a MVCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know what's going on without seeing code for `CDialog`.  Is "func1" virtual in `CDialog`?  If so, you can write:

```
void delayed_call_func1(CDialog& cdialog)
{
    ... ;
    cdialog.func1(v);
}
```

If not, you could indeed use a template:

```
template <typename CDlgX>
void delayed_call_func1(CDlgX* p)
{
    ... ;
    p->func1(v);
}
```

Or, if your old compiler can compile boost, there are several libraries therein such as [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/function.html) that are similar to the C++11 [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and can be used to supply `delayed_call_func1` with an arbitrary callback to your member function, but I'd suggest you only look into that after updating your compiler - then you can use lambdas too.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I didn't phrase it correctly. In my attempts to abbreviate my actual code I butchered it. I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959965/error-c2975-in-a-template-function-implementation) since it will be too much if I edit it out here.